# Red Hat Directory Server - Escape special characters

Tags: java, ldap, redhat

I am getting error "Error while performing search ERR_04149 Not a valid escaped value" when running the following search query against Red Hat Directory Server:

cn=cn\3DnsPwPolicyEntry\,ou\3Dinternal\,o\3Dcompany\,c\3Dgr,cn=nsPwPolicyContainer,ou=internal,o=company,c=gr

Any ideas on how to escape characters properly?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [LDAP wiki](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/DN%20Escape%20Values), the characters that need escaping are:

> comma ,
>   Backslash character \
>   Pound sign (hash sign) #
>   Plus sign + 
>   Less than symbol <
>   Greater than symbol >
>   Semicolon ;
>   Double quote (quotation mark) "
>   Equal sign =
>   Leading or trailing spaces

It looks like you're trying to escape numbers, which do not need to be escaped.

Also, the following characters don't need to be escaped either:

```
* ( ) . & - _ [ ] ` ~ | @ $ % ^ ? : { } ! '
```

Comment: Actually what I am trying to do is to perform an LDAP lookup on this DN: cn=cn\3DnsPwPolicyEntry\,ou\3Dinternal\,o\3Dcompany\,c\3Dgr,cn=nsPwPolicyContainer,ou=internal,o=company,c=gr .Although I can verify the existence of this D.N. every time I open the Apache Directory Studio, I cannot search for it and I am failing to make a successful LDAP query in Java.

Answer (score 0):

> cn=cn\3DnsPwPolicyEntry,ou\3Dinternal,o\3Dcompany,c\3Dgr,cn=nsPwPolicyContainer,ou=internal,o=company,c=gr

This looks bogus to me because this RDN value looks like you've escaped all equal signs with the byte-encoding:

```
cn\3DnsPwPolicyEntry\,ou\3Dinternal\,o\3Dcompany\,c\3Dgr
```

You would have to also escape the comma if you really want to use that value. I'm pretty sure one usually don't add entries with such an RDN beneath *cn=nsPwPolicyContainer,ou=internal,o=company,c=gr*. There seems to be another issue in whatever code you're using.

To avoid such issues without having to dive into [RFC 4514](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514) I strongly recommend to use a decent LDAP module package for your favourite programming language with decent quoting functions and not roll your own home-grown script.

Answer (score 0):

This string worked for me:

```
String globalPolicyDn="cn=cn\\3DnsPwPolicy\\,ou\\3Dinternal\\,o\\3Dcompany\\,c\\3Dgr,cn=nsPwPolicyContainer,ou=internal,o=company,c=gr";
```